# Break the CompletableFutures chain

Tags: java, asynchronous, future, completable-future

You can chain running blocks with `CompletableFuture` like this:

```
CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(block1)
    .thenApply(block2)
    .thenApply(block3)...
```

My function returns one such `CompletableFuture` with 2 blocks, so user can continue chaining more if he wants.

```
public CompletableFuture foo() {
    return CompletableFuture
               .supplyAsync(block1).
               .thenApply(block2);
}
```

User may use this like:

```
foo().thenApply(block3).join();
```

I want to add `.exceptionaly()` handler in my method (so user does not see it), but one that can **break** the chain and any possible user chain if any of my blocks fails! In other words - if `block1` or `block2` fails, I don't want to continue with any possible user blocks (`block3`) that he can chain onto the return value of `foo`.

Bonus question: is there something better then `CompletableFuture` in Java world?

Comment: Your request doesn't fit with the intention of `CompletableFuture`. If you complete the `CompletableFuture` with an exception, then chained functions/handlers should have to deal with that exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why this would work. Simple because `thenAsync` may change the type value of what is returned (from `CompletableFuture<A>` to `CompletableFuture<B>`) and in method `foo` we can't know what blocks user will add.

So this idea is not natural and this is not how futures work.